# iAd error: Ad Inventory unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iad

I am in the final stages of an app and I have been testing my ad-enabled app on both my iPhone (4S, iOS 6.0) and iPad (3, iOS 5.1.1).

My app is an iPhone app (i.e. it runs on iPad as an iPhone app) and I used the same XCode project to run my app on the two devices.

The curious thing, is that on my iPhone I see the iAd test ads, and on the iPad (also connected to my Wifi) I don't. I see the following error in the console:

```
{ ADInternalErrorCode = 3; NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Ad inventory unavailable"; }
```

A few people on this site have mentioned the same problem and people generally attribute it to normal behaviour with reasoning that perhaps there are simply no ads to serve to the iAd banner at the time.

This would be fine, but it doesn't explain why it would work on my iPhone and not the iPad; which are both using the same internet connection as well.

Does anyone have any theories/solutions for this?

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: It may be a bad height constraint - see my answer there http://stackoverflow.com/a/33945790/1396265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is probably serving a different selection of ads to iPhone and iPad users. Either that, or there's something else about your profiles on the two devices that's causing the iPhone to receive some ads that the iPad doesn't. (Some ads may be targeted to specific market segments, based on any number of factors.)