# iOS 9 - Ad inventory unavailable

Tags: ios, iad, ios9, xcode7, adbannerview

After updating to Xcode 7 and building my app in iOS9, iAds stopped working and I get this error in `bannerView`

> didFailToReceiveAdWithError:
>
> Ad inventory unavailable.

Any ideas?

EDIT: iAds are now working. Apple must have fixed it after we filed bug reports on the issue.

Comment: Assuming these are test ads. Ads come and go, sometimes not always available. How long did you wait?

Comment: Test ads. I'm currently developing this app, so I have it up for long periods of time, 20 minutes or more. I have yet to see the test ad.

Comment: I've been making ios apps for 5 years. I know it can take a few minutes sometimes for an ad to show up. This appears to be different.

Comment: Usually iAds are a no-brainer, they just work. Are you doing a simple enable, nothing fancy?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, @YiminRong. I agree, i've never had trouble before. No nothing fancy, just displaying the adbannerview at the top of my root view.

Comment: Did u find any solution for this?

Comment: @NAZIK, As I mentioned in the EDIT, they just started working without me doing anything, so I think Apple fixed the issue at the time. I haven't been working on an app for a sec, so I'm not sure what is currently happening.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Xcode 7.3.1` and I received the same error. After I renewed my membership I was able to click at the `contracts,tax and banking information` section. I saw that there wasn't a contract type for the `iAd App Network` anymore..only a contract type for paid applications. So my suggestion is that Apple does not support `iAd` anymore.
In that case I would recommend to have a look on `AdMob`(Google Advertising).

Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros

Answer (score 0):

You may have set an invalid (height) constraint for the `ADBannerView`. Please check the constraints for it.

In my case I had a wrong height constraint set in the storyboard scene. The height was set to 32 which is an invalid height for iPhone portrait mode. When I removed the bad constraint, the error ("Ad inventory unavailable") disappeared and the ads were delivered as before.

Likely the issue may appear as ads working on one device and not on another. (see [iAd error: Ad Inventory unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14299764/1396265)) I assume that the constraints match valid ad dimensions on one device but do not match the valid dimensions on the other device and then ads only work on one device and not on the other.