# iAds banner is not appearing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad, adbannerview

I added the `iAd framework`. I drag and dropped the `iAdBannerView` onto the view controller. Then I set constraints for the banner. Next I connected the banner to the `ViewController.swift` file. After doing so I wrote this code :-

**On top of file :**

```
import iAd
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate
```

{

**Creating the outlet :**

```
@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView!
```

**In viewDidLoad() :**

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
self.adBannerView.delegate = self
self.adBannerView.hidden = true
```

**Next I created these two functions :**

```
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

    return true

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    adBannerView.hidden = false
}
```

This is all I did. I didn't fill any form on iTunes connect or import any other framework related to iAds. This is literally all that I have done.

But yet when I ran the app on the simulator, the iAd banner did not show up. It did not even show the Ads by Apple. Nothing at all. It just blended in with the app. I ran the app on my phone, and still nothing. I uploaded the app to the AppStore, and I still don't see anything when I download my app from the AppStore. Any idea what went wrong here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: u having problem in device or simulator. In India and some other country iAd wont work on device but it definately work on simulator

Comment: @vaibby I am having a problem on both device and simulator

Comment: try working on constraints u set on adBannerView. Also check view height / width

Comment: @vaibby I tried printing the frame of the banner, and it fell within the frame of the view, and right where it should be. But it doesn't appear for some reason.

Comment: You should also add the method `func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!)` and print the error, so you know what iAd complains about. As already suggested by vaibby, please check the dimensions of the ad banner view - see also my answer there http://stackoverflow.com/a/33945790/1396265

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I had previously added that function, and I was getting an error repeatedly. Also, there is no problem with the constraints.

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I got the I error which I wanted to be printed if the banner view failed to load.

Comment: Can you copy&paste the exact error message?

Comment: See, all I did was write this code-`func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
print("Error!")
}`
In the console I got the error - `Error!`

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function and enter it into `viewDidLoad` (it helps organize). After you are done with that enter this in.

```
func iAD() {

    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": bannerView]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView.hidden = true
}
```

Then when you open it up you should get [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQZ6.png)

Comment: It didn't work. Nothing showed up. The banner failed to receive the ad.